# Workflow for taking a percentage of a payment (PayPal)

Tags: e-commerce, paypal

I'm implementing a business model where the service takes 10% of a fee.  For example, the user lists a product for $100.  The buyer purchases it.  $90 goes to the seller, $10 is collected by the site.

Does anyone know offhand if this is feasible with Paypal.  In theory all the money could go into our PayPal account and then a $90 payment could be made behind the scenes to the seller's account.  Is it possible to programatically schedule a depsoit?

We also have the option of using a merchant gateway like Authorize.

Ideas appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

look into paypal adoptive payments (beta) www.x.com , they allow you to distribute payments into multiple receiver.

if you want to schedule payments i think you can use the mass pay API to programmatically send payments from the PP account. But using the beta adoptive payments is much much easier.

Comment: Just to be precise, it's "Adaptive".

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can programmatically do a deposit to the seller's account. Paypal calls it Mass Pay.

You pay 2% for the deposit, with a cap. So it might make sense to pool the funds before you deposit them.